# I'm having trouble using react-saga-test-plan

Tags: redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

The following code is a demo given by the official

```
import { call, put, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { expectSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan'

function * userSaga (api) {
  const action = yield take('REQUEST_USER')
  const user = yield call(api.fetchUser, action.payload)

  yield put({ type: 'RECEIVE_USER', payload: user })
}

it('just works!', () => {
  const api = {
    fetchUser: id => ({ id, name: 'Tucker' })
  }

  return expectSaga(userSaga, api)
    // Assert that the `put` will eventually happen.
    .put({
      type: 'RECEIVE_USER',
      payload: { id: 42, name: 'Tucker' }
    })

    // Dispatch any actions that the saga will `take`.
    .dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_USER', payload: 42 })

    // Start the test. Returns a Promise.
    .run()
})
```

But the result is actually an error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obaBm.jpg)

The following is the version information:

```
"redux-saga": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
"redux-saga-test-plan": "^3.7.0"
```

Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[warning when install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KneJv.jpg)

I changed the version of redux-saga and it was normal.

So, it should be redux-saga-test-plan does not support the beta version of redux-saga.